# Search for full name using dir and use the result in another command

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file

I run a batch file with parameters (filename, folder etc.).

The file name is unique but incomplete so I use `dir /b %SearchFolder% | find %FileName%` to find its full name, but I can't put it in as a parameter to another command.

I tried:

```bash
dir /b %SearchFolder% | find %FileName% > aa
echo %aa%
```

I also tried:

```bash
aa=dir /b %SearchFolder% | find %FileName%
```

Comment: One of these should get you closer: ```For %%G In ("%SearchFolder%\*%FileName%*") Do YourCommand "%%G"```, or ```For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir "%SearchFolder%\*%FileName%*" /A:-D /B 2^>NUL') Do YourCommand "%SearchFolder%\%%G"```. Please in future use the search facility, [here are some basic search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=result+command+variable+%5Bbatch-file%5D).

Comment: I did this and it worked until I changed something and forgot what it was

For /f  %%A in ('dir /b %SearchFolder% ^| find "20513-110470"')
 Do (
 echo hello1

  Set vartmp=%%A
)
echo %vartmp%

Comment: How about you use the code I gave you, instead of continuing with the less efficient version you started with!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
set "FileName=full/partial file name"
set "SearchFolder=D:\some_path" 

dir "%SearchFolder%" /a:-d /b/s | find "%FileName%" >aa.txt
set /p aa=<aa.txt
echo %aa%
del aa.txt
```

Note that:

- Use `dir /s` to include all subfolders in the search process.
- Use `dir /a:-d` to search only for files and exclude folders.
- It is recommended to Enclose search path/s with double quotes, As for search strings in the `find` command is a must.
- When you redirect command output to a file using `>` or `<` it is a good idea to add a proper file extension (aa.txt, aa.csv, aa.bat, ...etc).
- It would help if you define and declare a variable before using it with `echo` or any other command.